# how use matchpattern() to find certain aminoacid in a file with many sequence(.fasta) in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, fasta, bioconductor

I have a file (mydata.txt) that contains many exon sequences with [**fasta**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fasta) format. I want to find start ('atg') and stop ('taa','tga','tag') codons for each DNA sequence (considering the frame). I tried using `matchPattern` ( a function from the [**`Biostrings`**](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.12/bioc/html/Biostrings.html) R package) to find theses amino acids:

As an example mydata.txt could be:

```
>a
atgaatgctaaccccaccgagtaa
>b
atgctaaccactgtcatcaatgcctaa
>c
atggcatgatgccgagaggccagaataggctaa
>d
atggtgatagctaacgtatgctag
>e
atgccatgcgaggagccggctgccattgactag

file=read.fasta(file="mydata.txt") 
matchPattern( "atg" , file)
```

Note: read.fasta is a function in `seqinr` package that used to import fasta format files.

But this commands didn't work! How can I use this function to find start and stop codons in each exon sequence? (without frame shifting)

Comment: It's probably easier if you first convert to AA with the frame you want and then search for the start-codon and extract the protein sequence until the stop codon...

Comment: You should present all the start and stop codons as R vectors and use dput(head(mydata)) rather than making us retrace your unspecified steps in reading in these strings into the workspace.

Comment: @Arun: The frequency of each codon that codes same AA is important for me. So, convert to AA wouldn't be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'subject' argument for `matchPattern` is a special object (e.g. XString). You can convert your sequences to XStrings by collapsing them with paste and using `?BString`.

So, with your data:

```
file = read.fasta(file = "mydata.txt")

# find 'atg' locations
atg <- lapply(file, function(x) {
  string <- BString(paste(x, collapse = ""))
  matchPattern("atg", string)
})

atg[1:2]
# $a
#   Views on a 18-letter BString subject
# subject: atgacccccaccgagtaa
# views:
#     start end width
# [1]     1   3     3 [atg]
#
# $b
#  Views on a 21-letter BString subject
# subject: atgcccactgtcatcacctaa
# views:
#     start end width
# [1]     1   3     3 [atg]
```

For a simple example, finding the number and locations of 'atg's in a sequence:

```
sequence <- BString("atgatgccatgcccccatgcatgatatg")
result <- matchPattern("atg", sequence)
#   Views on a 28-letter BString subject
# subject: atgatgccatgcccccatgcatgatatg
# views:
#     start end width
# [1]     1   3     3 [atg]
# [2]     4   6     3 [atg]
# [3]     9  11     3 [atg]
# [4]    17  19     3 [atg]
# [5]    21  23     3 [atg]
# [6]    26  28     3 [atg]

# Find out how many 'atg's were found
length(result)
# [1] 6

# Get the start site of each 'atg'
result@ranges@start
# [1]  1  4  9 17 21 26
```

Also, check out `?DNAString` and `?RNAString`. They are similar to `BString` only they are limited to nucleotide characters, and allow for quick comparisons between DNA and RNA sequences.

Edit to address frame shifting concern mentioned in the comments:
You can subset the result to get those 'atg's that are in frame using the modulo trick mentioned by @DWin.

```
# assuming the first 'atg' sets the frame
in.frame.result <- result[(result@ranges@start - result@ranges@start[1]) %% 3 == 0]
# Views on a 28-letter DNAString subject
# subject: ATGATGCCATGCCCCCATGCATGATATG
# views:
#     start end width
# [1]     1   3     3 [ATG]
# [2]     4   6     3 [ATG]

# There are two 'atg's in frame in this result
length(in.frame.result)
# [1] 2

# With your data:
file = read.fasta(file = "mydata.txt")
atg <- lapply(file, function(x) {
  string <- BString(paste(x, collapse = ""))
  result <- matchPattern("atg", string)
  result[(result@ranges@start - result@ranges@start[1]) %% 3 == 0]
})
```

Comment: @ Eric: Thanks. Your commands work but it is important to find atg without frame shifting.

Comment: For the record, I would go with @DWin's answer unless you absolutely need to use the Biostrings package. `gregexpr` is faster and you don't have to deal with weird S4 objects. That said, this answer explains why you couldn't get `matchPattern` to work with your fasta object (i.e. the fasta object stores each nucleotide of the sequence separately in a vector, so they need to be collapsed for use with either `gregexpr` or `matchPattern`.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard for me to believe this hasn't yet been done by one of the BioC packages, but if you want to do it with base R functionality, then consider using `gregexpr`

```
x <- c(a='atgaatgctaaccccaccgagtaa', 
  b='atgctaaccactgtcatcaatgcctaa', 
  c='atggcatgatgccgagaggccagaataggctaa', 
  d='atggtgatagctaacgtatgctag', 
  e='atgccatgcgaggagccggctgccattgactag')

starts<-lapply(gregexpr("atg", x), function(x) x[ (x-x[1] %% 3) == 0])
stops <- mapply(function(strg, starts) {poss <- gregexpr("taa|tga|tag", strg) ; poss[[1]][ ( (poss[[1]]-starts) )%% 3 == 0]}, x, starts=unlist(starts))
 stops
#--------------
$a
[1] 22

$b
[1] 25

$c
[1]  7 31

$d
[1] 22

$e
[1] 31
```

You  check to see if the stop codons are "in frame" reads by checking the distance being evenly divisible by 3:

```
> (25-1)%%3
[1] 0
```

Comment: There are bioC packages in this subject. But I try to do it because they don't have all capabilities that I need. In my data, all sequences have a start (atg) and a stop codon (taa , tga or tag).

Comment: I want to detect stop and strat codon in each exon sequence and define them in R to detect other codons in correct frame.

Comment: So you need to heed my earlier advice and edit your question to include examples with your desired complexity and precise definition of values. It appears you want to determine the length of transcribed sequences, but you have not specified what to do with a bunch of edge cases. (I'm tired of guessing about all this stuff.)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I've made some changes in my question. I think now it has all necessary information.