# How to find certain sequence in a file (.fasta) in R if it can be separated by "-"

Tags: r, sequence

I want to find the position of a sequence e.g."atgcgctcgactcca" in a fasta file. 
I have already found a way to do this with the following function which I got from this question:
[how use matchpattern() to find certain aminoacid in a file with many sequence(.fasta) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913458/how-use-matchpattern-to-find-certain-aminoacid-in-a-file-with-many-sequence-f)

```
asdf<-read.table(file = "TSS_00001_ONACali.fa")

SequenzPosition <- lapply(asdf, function(x) {
  string <- BString(paste(x, collapse = ""))
  matchPattern("atgcgctcgactcca", string)
 })
```

But my problem is that the sequence might also be split by "-" in the file; for example like this: "atgc---gctcgact--cca".

Is there a way to make the function ignore "-"?

Thank you already in advance!

Comment: use `gsub` to remove all the hyphens.

Comment: Nucleotides in fasta separated with `-`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I can't remove the hyphens because I need to know the position in the file with hyphens.

Comment: @Pgibas It is an alignment of 2 files. So if there was an insertion in the one file, I get a "-" in the other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write your own simple code to ignore "-"

here's the core code :

```
> temp = s2c(sequence)

> newsequence = c2s( temp[temp != "-"] )
```

c2s() and s2c() are functions from "seqinr" package

yo can also use other packages outside R like mummer or Blast+ that resulting readable outputs

if the positions are important you could use the code below to retreive the right index :

```
> which(temp != "-")[i]    #put the the temp index instead of i
```

Comment: But then the I get the wrong position. I need the position of the sequence with all the hyphens.

Comment: yourwelcome, but if your work is this things you should learn working with MUMMER and Blast+ packages, strong tools for alignment of genomic data

Comment: this is not my "work". I am doing my bachelor about comparing genes. I already  learn R for this. I have not enough time to learn MUMMER and Blast+

Comment: I'm new to this field too, and learning Mummer and Blast is easy, not need lots of time to learn, just install the packages and try reading their helps, you just need to save your genomic data with writeXStringset() and run Mummer and or Blast, those are powerful tools

Comment: "voting up requires 15 reputation" - Sorry I only got 8 >.< But I would vote it up if I could